# HP 2013 UltraSlim Docking Station Crashes\Freezes HP Elitebook 840 G1

Tags: laptop, freeze, docking-station

We have a user that when they disconnect HP Elitebook 840 G1 from the docking station the system then crashes\freezes no BSOD but they always nearly always require a restart.

The devices are compatible and we have many users working fine with this setup. 
I have updated the firmware and checked that the "when the lid is closed" settings are all correct.

The spec of the machine has no bearing on the ability to work with the docking station as all systems are company standard and all the rest are working.

OS: W7

Any help would be appreciated.

Will update with any relevant information as it becomes available.

Answer (score 1):

Analyzing the crash dump will provide you way more information and most likely find the root cause of the problem.

Location is normally:

C:\windows\Minidump

Use WinDbg to read the crash dump

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved itself we're unsure why, we tried a Firmware update which failed and haven't made any significant changes.

No other user has reported this issue. If another user does report this issue and we find a resolution I will post here. :)